# combination of several variables in driver

Tags: drivers

I am looking for a tutorial or example of a blend file showing in the drivers the **combination** of several variables

thanks

Comment: Asking for tutorials is considered off topic here. Could rephrase your question differently so it focuses more on the problem and shows what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

It's really pretty simple. You hit 'Add Variable' several times, pick the sources you want, name the variables in their top most fields more intelligently than me and then use the exact same names in the expression.

In this example, I just add the Y values of the latin gang together and drive Bombo's Y axis with them.

1.055 + 1.138 + 0.906 = 3.099

[image: vroom vroom honk]